# ACPI error is making my drive completely unusable

Tags: boot, live-usb, acpi

I brought my Acer Aspire laptop with me on a plane trip, but it has sat in my bag for a while and totally run out of battery. Upon powering it up, I was brought to the GRUB boot screen rather than booting straight into Ubuntu as usual. After pressing Enter on the default Ubuntu boot option, these errors appear:

[image]

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls/dev)

ALERT! UUID=77e0d826-49c5-4a2a-a481-99eb1d1ae93a does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) built-in shell (ash)   
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

and I'm left in a shell where I can't really do anything.

I made a live USB and used it to boot my laptop to try to get all the important files off before reinstalling Ubuntu. When I click “Try Ubuntu”, the same errors as in the top 5 lines briefly occupy the screen before loading normally. The problem is that the only disk that the live environment recognises in `lsblk` is the USB stick, not the internal hard drive. I suspect something has become corrupted, but I am no expert.

The only thing I have been able to try in addressing this issue is adding `acpi=off` to the end of the file after typing `e` in GRUB, and it changed nothing. There are also no BIOS settings that seem to affect anything. I have no further intuition as to how to solve this issue, and would prefer to get some files off this than wipe the whole thing. Does anyone know how this can be addressed?

Comment: Check BIOS/UEFI. If the drive isn't recognized there as I suspect it won't, then there's your problem, not Ubuntu's.

Comment: You didn't happen to launch yourself into LEO and get hit by a bunch of cosmic rays, did you? Because flash drives generally die a gradual death with the final state being a read-only storage device rather than something that doesn't appear at all. If it's at all possible, I would recommend extracting the flash storage and connecting it to a USB adapter to try and recover the data. They are (usually) more lax with regards to hardware failures than a motherboard.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that these ACPI errors are irrelevant to your problem

Comment: The error appears to be caused by the laptop sitting in your bag until it ran completely out of power, in which case it is a common error and it should be possible to fix it.

Comment: @karel no, all the answers on that other question either talk about RAID settings that I do not have or mention doing some configuration with a file system or storage device which I can not access.